# jQuery dialog on IFrame (containing PDF doc) overlapping in IE

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a jQuery dialog on top of PDF doc in IFrame. When I click a button in my Form, a jQuery dialog pops up. Problem is that the Popup is going behind the PDF doc instead of displaying at the top of the Viewport. This problem occurs only in IE (6,7 and 8). Firefox displays the elements correctly without any overlapping issue.

I tried setting the **position: relative** and **z-index:** , but no luck !

Please Help.

Thanks in advance !